# return a C++ pointer to Boost python that doesn't get garbage collected

Tags: python, c++, boost

I want to return a C++ pointer to Python using boost. But, I don't want Boost to call the destructor for me.

The first attempt used  `return_value_policy<manage_new_object>`. So my C++ looks as follows. I first declare a function `returnsFooPtr()`, and then I expose it to Python.

```
Foo * returnsFooPtr(std::string param)
{
    return FooFactory::getFooFromParam(param);
}

def("returnsFooPtr", &returnsFooPtr, return_value_policy<manage_new_object>());
```

The problem is that according to `manage_new_object`, python takes over the object ownership. And therefore would free the object once it falls out of scope. My python code looks like this

```
for param in allParams:
    print " calling returnsFooPtr with param " , param
    someFoo = CppBinding.returnsFooPtr(param)
```

That means each time in my loop, the old `someFoo` falls out of scope. And would thus call the destructor of the C++ Foo. I added printout in destructor of Foo

```
~Foo()
{
    cout << "SOMEONE TRYING TO CALL DTOR on FOO!!!!" << endl;
}
```

Here's output

```
....
....
calling returnsFooPtr with param param1
SOMEONE TRYING TO CALL DTOR on FOO!!!!
```

Can I tell Python to *not* free objects? The reason I want this is that my Foo object actually comes from a HashMap of Foo * (`map<string, Foo*`>), and I might need to reuse them. For example, there might be repeats in my params in python. So say I create a Foo * for param1 that came from python. Later, in python, I get a repeat of param1, so I do `someFoo = CppBinding.returnsFooPtr(param1)` again. Problem is, param1's Foo already got destroyed.

I think I'm ok with never destroying any of the Foo objects. I know this will leak memory, but I'd rather leak memory than try to access objects that's already been destroyed.

Comment: Seeing as you are returning a reference or pointer to an existing object, probably `reference_existing_object` would be the policy to use.

Comment: Maybe a silly proposal, but why don't you use shared pointers? What you seem to be describing is essentially sharing a single instance between Python, C++ and also different parts of code, and keeping it alive while it is in use. Shared pointers would also make sure it gets destroyed when not used, and they are wrapped by Python really nicely.